# Most memory efficient way to transpose a large file in C++

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I have an input file, which is 40,000 columns by 2 million rows. This file is roughly 70GB in memory and thus to large to fit in memory at one go.

I need to effectively transpose this file, however there are some lines which are junk and should not be added to the output.

How I have currently implemented this is using ifstream and a nested get line, which effectively reads the whole file into memory (and thus lets the OS handle memory management), and then outputs the transpose like this. This works in an acceptable timescale however obviously has a large memory footprint for the application.

I now have to run this program on a cluster which makes me specify memory requirements ahead of time, and thus a large memory footprint increases job queuing time in the cluster.

I feel there has to be a more memory efficient approach to doing this. One thought I had was using mmap, which would allow me to do the transposition without reading the file into memory at all. Are there any other alternatives?

To be clear, I am happy to use any language and any method that can do this in a reasonable amount of time (my current program takes around 4 minutes on this large file on a local workstation).

Thanks

Comment: How is the data stored? Stringified as CSV?

Comment: Why not read a single line at a time and decide if it should go to the output or not?

Comment: Thats what I do - but most lines are needed. Line by line doesn't work for the transpose as I have to store the information somewhere. The format is space delimited, with some lines just being strings (the ones that aren't in the output)

Comment: Sounds to me as the worst idea in the world to store such data as text. Consider plain binary or HDF5, which will provide a way to access the data you need accurately with no iteration requirement. And btw, in every optimization concept, there's nothing such as "transposing" such a huge matrix. You simply read what you need of it, which is, again, why you should never store this as text.

Comment: If it runs on a local workstation in 4 minutes and that's acceptable, then request the same amount of resources you have on the local workstation.  I doubt a local workstation has more RAM than a compute node on a cluster.

Comment: The most memory efficient solution would exchange one byte at a time. Are you sure you want the most memory efficient way?

Comment: The local workstation has 64GB of RAM and is managed by us, thus allowing for effectively unlimited virtual memory. The cluster, of course has much much more memory available but requesting more than 64GB of RAM results in very long queuing times (about 1 hour) which is unacceptable. @IInspectable a memory efficient solution which is not slow, and also I still need to store the data! Unfortunately this is output from a program we cannot change, all of our data is stored in HDF5 or binary formats. Do you all think preprocessing the output would be the best then?

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do this with a pre-processing pass over the file, that only needs to have a line at a time in its working set.

Filter the junk and make every line the same (binary) size.

Now, you can memory map the temp file, and stride the columns as rows for the output.

Comment: How would you best suggest I do the preprocessing pass? Should I use awk or similar? The problem is the junk files are actually metadata for the data that follows, so although they are not final input they are actually quite important to determine what is in the file.

Comment: @DavidWilson whatever you are familiar with. Parsing relevant metadata that will make the outputting easier is a good idea

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way for you to do this would be to instead parse each line and find out whether it is junk or not.  After this, you could put the remaining lines into output.  This may take more time, but it would save a lot of memory and save you from using so much for lines which are completely useless to any text you are trying to print.  However, using an mmap would also be a great way to achieve your goal

Hope this helps!!